# Java, compare values of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

My code is here:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

list1.add(4444);
list1.add(4444);

System.out.println(list1.get(0) == list1.get(1));
```

It print out as false. What is the reason? normally 4444 == 4444 should be true.
Thank you.

Comment: yes, this answered my question. thank you guys.

Comment: You can also do `System.out.println(list1.get(0) == (int)list1.get(1));` and that will print `true`.

Answer (score 2):

`List` (and other `Collection` subclasses) store **objects**, not **primitives**.

In Java 4 and before, `list1.add(4444);` would have been a compilation error.

Since Java 5, there is autoboxing: if you pass a primitive in a place that expects an instance of an object, the JVM automatically converts it to its wrapper value. So you end with your code working like `list1.add(Integer.valueOf(4444))`.

When you do the `get`, you are comparing not two primitives but two objects, so you must use `.equals()` to compare them.

Funny nitpick, because of how `Integer.valueOf`, if you had used `111` (or anything in the -128 to 127 range) in your example, your comparation would have returned `true`, since for those values the instances of integer are in a cache and `Integer.valueOf` returns always the same instance, not a new one.